# current_user.id changing, but no modification function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a small application that has a profile which renders 'stats', showing the number of followers and the following you have. You can click on that to see the list of your followers/following, then click on one of them to see that person's profile. Problem is, when I go to this person's profile, current_user.id changes to that person's. I have no code that directly modifies current_user.

I do have kind of 2 user controllers - one I made to have the follow/following functions, and the ones provided by devise. I feel like the problem might be coming from this, but I am not sure.

controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following
    render 'profiles/show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user  = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers
    render 'profiles/show_follow'
  end
end
```

views/profiles/show.html.erb:

```
<h1> PROFILE  </h1>

<% if(@profile.id == current_user.id)  %>
<!-- If user logged in we can view this -->
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<li class="round-image-50"><%= image_tag(@profile.avatar.url(:thumb)) %> </li>
<div>  
<b>First name: </b><%= @profile.first_name %> <br/>
</div>

<div>
<b>Last name: </b><%= @profile.last_name %><br />
</div>

<div>
<b>About me: </b><%= @profile.about_me %><br />
</div>

</p>

<section class="stats">
  <%= render 'stats' %>
</section>

<%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_profile_path(current_user) %>
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>

<% else %>

</div>
<li class="round-image-50"><%= image_tag(@profile.avatar.url(:thumb)) %> </li>
<div>  
<b>First name: </b><%= @profile.first_name %> <br/>
</div>

<div>
<b>Last name: </b><%= @profile.last_name %><br />
</div>

<div>
<b>About me: </b><%= @profile.about_me %><br />
</div>

</p>

<section class="stats">
  <%= render 'stats', locals: {profile: @profile.id}  %>
</section>

<%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
<% end %>
```

views/profiles/_stats.html.erb:

```
<% @user.id = @profile.id %>
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>"> 
    <strong id="following" class="stat">
      <%= @user.following.count %>
    </strong>
    following
  </a>
  <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
    <strong id="followers" class="stat">
      <%= @user.followers.count %>
    </strong>
    followers
  </a>
</div>
```

**EDIT: profiles_controller and show_follow**

profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  # GET /profiles/1
  # GET /profiles/1.json
  def show
    @profile=Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /profiles/new
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  # GET /profiles/1/edit
  def edit
    @profile=Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
  end

  # POST /profiles
  # POST /profiles.json
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    @profile=Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_profile
    @profile=Profile.find_by user_id: current_user.id
    end

  #Note: update this everytime we add a new attribute to Profile model
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :about_me, :avatar)
    end
end
```

views/profiles/show_follow.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<h3><%= @title %></h3>
<% if @users.any? %>
  <ul class="users follow">
    <% puts @user.username %>
    <% @users.each do |person| %>
    <%= link_to person.username, profile_path(person.id) %><br>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you show the content of your `show_follow` partial? as well as that of your `ProfilesController`?

Comment: Just edited the two in.

Comment: Ha... guessing as much... Observe your first line in the `stats` partial: `<% @user.id = @profile.id %>` are you sure you want that?

Comment: How does that affect current_user though? Isn't @user just an instance variable?

Comment: Where exactly is `current_user` being defined? I suspect that `current_user` is being set incorrectly. Probably just based on `params[:user_id]` or something of that sort instead of a session variable when user logs in.